# How to change the wsdl url of cxf endpoint?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, apache-camel

I am trying to create a proxy service using apache camel through camel configuration file.

I have successfully created the proxy service for version webservice of axis 2 .

The only problem is that , the proxy service final wsdl url and the address both point to the same url.

Here is my camel-config.xml file part :

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="securityService"
                   address="https://0.0.0.0:9080/services/version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint"
                   endpointName="s:version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint"                
                   serviceName="s:version"
                   wsdlURL="etc/version.wsdl"
                   xmlns:s="http://axisversion.sample"/>
```

Now the only problem is from the above configuration, if i have to see the wsdl of the above service.
My wsdl url will be:

```
https://0.0.0.0:9080/services/version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint?wsdl
```

And the soap address location will be :

```
soap:address location="https://0.0.0.0:9080/services/version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint"
```

Now what i want is that the wsdl url should be different from the soap address location i.e.

The wsdl url should be :

```
https://0.0.0.0:9080/services/version.Security?wsdl
```

and the soap address location should be like:

```
soap:address location="https://0.0.0.0:9080/services/version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint"
```

How can i do the above. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the CxfEndpoint by adding a properties setting just like

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="securityService"
                   address="https://0.0.0.0:9080/services/version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint"
                   endpointName="s:version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint"                
                   serviceName="s:version"
                   wsdlURL="etc/version.wsdl"
                   xmlns:s="http://axisversion.sample">
   <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="publishedEndpointUrl" value="http://www.simple.com/services/test" />
   </cxf:properties>

   </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Comment: Hi Willem, Whwn i do the above configuration, upon testing on soap ui it gives error as <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
      <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
      <p>
         Problem accessing /services/version.Security.version.SecurityHttpsSoap11Endpoint. Reason:
         <pre>Not Found</pre>
      </p>
      <hr/>
      <i>
         <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
      </i>
   </body>
</html>  My publishedEndpointURL is HTTP based and wsdl url is also http based

Comment: The publishedEndpointUrl is for update the wsdl service address definiton. It's not the service url that you can access from SOAP UI. Can you double check it?

Comment: thanks for the help willem. But i want to make my publishedEndpointUrl as the service url. Can it be done?